# Inexplicable NameError with command-line Python

Tags: python, oop

I am working my way through the excellent 'Python The Hard Way' and copied the following code into a file called mystuff.py:

```
class MyStuff(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tangerine = "And now a thousand years between"

    def apple(self):
        print "I AM CLASSY APPLES!"
```

In terminal:

```
import mystuff

thing = MyStuff()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'MyStuff' is not defined
```

This has been happening repeatedly with other simple classes today. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want `thing = mystuff.MyStuff()`  (assuming `mystuff` is the name of the file where the class `MyStuff` resides).

The issue here is with how python handles namespaces.  You bring something into the current namespace by importing it, but there's a lot of flexibility in how you merge the namespaces from one file into another.  For example,

```
import mystuff
```

brings everything from the mystuff (module/file level) namespace into your current namespace, but to access it, you need `mystuff.function_or_class_or_data`.  If you don't want to type `mystuff` all the time, you can change the name you use to reference it in the current module (file):

```
import mystuff as ms
```

now, you can acess `MyStuff` by:

```
thing = ms.MyStuff()
```

And (almost) finally, there's the `from mystuff import MyStuff`.  In this form, you bring `MyStuff` directly into your namespace, but nothing else from `mystuff` comes into your namespace.

Last, (and this one isn't recommended) `from mystuff import *`.  This works the same as the previous one, but it also grabs everything else in the `mystuff` file and imports that too.

Comment: 14:32:18 vs 14:32:19.  You win. :^)

Comment: So helpful and lucid. Wish that had been included in the tutorial example. Thanks! Will approve your answer when SO says I can.

Comment: @MikeGirard -- namespaces are a very fundamental concept in python, and I honestly believe they're one of the reasons that the syntax is so clean and powerful.  Trying to elucidate this is always a pleasure :).  Good luck learning Python.  Maybe someday you'll like it as much as I do.

Answer (score 5):

You are importing the module in to your local namespace, but not the class.  If you want to use the class with your current import, you need:

```
thing = mystuff.MyStuff()
```

If you want to use the declaration you have, you need:

```
from mystuff import MyStuff
```

Comment: Two good answers in less than two minutes. I could only pick one but I gave you a point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I guess u got what u need.But here is what's going on with it

```
import mystuff 

#with this type of import all the names in the `mystuff` module's namespace are not copied into current modules namespace.
```

So you need to use `mystuff.MyStuff()`

use `from mystuff import *` to copy names in the `mystuff` module's namespace to current module's namespace.Now you can directly use `thing=MyStuff()`

Comment: Python reference suggests to use 'import mystuff' kind of importing to know which actual namespace a 'name' belongs to.Good for debugging large programs